# For loop increment value when iterating through days of week

Tags: java, android

In my Android app i'm using the following `Map` to map the days of the `Calendar` class to `String`s:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>(7);
                                             // values of the Calendar field
map.put(Calendar.MONDAY, "Mon");             // 2
map.put(Calendar.TUESDAY, "Tue");            // 3
map.put(Calendar.WEDNESDAY, "Wed");          // 4
map.put(Calendar.THURSDAY, "Thu");           // 5
map.put(Calendar.FRIDAY, "Fri");             // 6
map.put(Calendar.SATURDAY, "Sat");           // 7
map.put(Calendar.SUNDAY, "Sun");             // 1
```

And adding `Button`s dynamically to a `LinearLayout` with the day text like this:

```
LinearLayout dayLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_days);

for(int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText(map.get(i));
    dayLayout.addView(button);
}
```

This works fine, but the list of `Button`s always start from Sunday regardless of the current `Locale`.

I'm trying to rewrite this loop so it takes the first day of the week into account.

Something like this:

```
LinearLayout dayLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_days);
int firstDayOfWeek = Calendar.getInstance().getFirstDayOfWeek();

for(int i = firstDayOfWeek; i <= 7; ???) { // this is where i'm stuck
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText(map.get(i));
    dayLayout.addView(button);
}
```

**The problem** is i cannot figure out the correct formula for fetching the days in the correct order.

If the first day of the week is Monday, the loop has to go as `2 3 4 5 6 7 1`.

I guess i have to play with the modulo operator, i just don't know how.

I'd really appreciate any advice, maybe my approach is completely wrong.

Comment: To clarify, do you want to be able to have any day be the first day of the week, or do you just want it to start with Monday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not use the numeric values of the `Calendar.*` constants.
The numeric values are implementation detail, not API, and should not be used directly like the for-loop tries.

It will be better to store the constants in a list:

```
List<Integer> days = Arrays.asList(
    Calendar.MONDAY,
    Calendar.TUESDAY,
    Calendar.WEDNESDAY,
    Calendar.TUESDAY,
    Calendar.FRIDAY,
    Calendar.SATURDAY,
    Calendar.SUNDAY
    );
```

And then find the index whose value corresponds to `firstDayOfWeek`:

```
int start = days.indexOf(firstDayOfWeek);
```

And then, create the correct map key by rotating the 0..6 indexes by the value of `start` and the modulo operator, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  int key = days.get((start + i) % 7);
  Button button = new Button(this);
  button.setText(map.get(key));
  dayLayout.addView(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with an `i` as `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`,
you can take these mod 7, giving `1 2 3 4 5 6 0`
and then add 1: giving `2 3 4 5 6 7 1`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe add a count into the for loop and compare count to 7, so that the loop will go through all 7 days regardless of the start.

so maybe something like this

```
LinearLayout dayLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_days);
int firstDayOfWeek = Calendar.getInstance().getFirstDayOfWeek();
int count = 1;

for(int i = firstDayOfWeek; count <= 7; i++) {

count++    
if(i <= 7)
    firstDayOfWeek = 1;

Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText(map.get(i));
dayLayout.addView(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an array like this:

```
int[] daysInWeek = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1]
```

Then solution should be:

```
// define day of week you want to print out first.
int firstDayOfWeekIndex = 0;  // print Monday first
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  int currentDay = (firstDayOfWeekIndex + i) % 7;
  String day = map.get(daysInWeek[currentDay]);

  // print this day to your button
  Button button = new Button(this);
  button.setText(day);
  dayLayout.addView(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you want?

```
Map<String, Integer> names = (new GregorianCalendar()).getDisplayNames(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

which gives

```
Tue, 3
Thu, 5
Sun, 1
Sat, 7
Wed, 4
Mon, 2
Fri, 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example that also removes the need for the Map so that weekdays are displayed in correct locale.

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
// Array with 8 elements (first is empty string), so Calendar constants correspond to the day.
String[] dayNames = symbols.getShortWeekdays();

int firstDayOfWeek = Calendar.getInstance().getFirstDayOfWeek();
int daysStart = Calendar.SUNDAY;
int daysEnd = Calendar.SATURDAY;
int dayCount = (daysEnd - daysStart) + 1; // +1 because both ends inclusive

for(int i = 0; i < dayCount; i++) {

    int day = firstDayOfWeek + i;
    if(day > daysEnd) // loop back if over the end
        day -= dayCount;

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText(dayNames[day]);
    dayLayout.addView(button);
}
```

Day starts at firstDayOfWeek: `2 3 4 5 6 7 1`
English:   `Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun`
Japanese: `月 火 水 木 金 土 日`